# Extracting structured data from any retail store receipt (Azure Computer Vision API OCR)

Tags: azure, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, vision-api

How can we extract structured data ( Merchant , Purchase Date , Tax , Total etc . ) from the text generated by Azure Computer Vision API OCR after scanning the  any retail store receipt . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Azure Form Recognizer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) for extracting structured data. It is also helpful in the extraction of tables.